# Algorithm to find the comparison between names / characters

Tags: algorithm, math, comparison, compare

I would like to ask a little attention to this challenge.

My intention is to find some solution to develop within the system.

In the business of my company (civil engineering) I have the following scenario:

We have the elements / materials registered in our database but our thousands of suppliers have the same elements / materials with different names but similar.

So I have a list of elements (e.g. cement) that came from an invoice through an XML.

On the other hand I have the same type of element registered in my database but with different name (in most case they are almost equal) and I want to find out in the invoice list which is more like comparing their names.

Is there any similar to the Bayesian algorithm in which I could compare the names and have a value between '0' and '1'? Where '1' would be 100% identical characters.

Example (I will change the type of elements for fruits):

If i have to compare: **raspberry**

```
Invoice List - Values of Algortim
---------------------------------
 strawberry ........ 0,89
 blueberry ......... 0,77
 cherry ............ 0,46
 grape ............. 0,11
 raspberry ......... 1,00
 pineapple ......... 0,13
```

The important is to find out the closest name when I do not have a perfect combination.

There are other techniques?

Would be a pleasure to see what you guys have in mind!

Comment: I'm trying ... I just need to accept the answer?

Thank you for that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure I am completely following - but if you are looking for a way to compute how two strings are similar to each other, you could try [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), it is often used for these purposes.

You can later normalize the result to get it in the range you desire, for example a simple normalization will be:

```
                                            distance(u,v)
normalized_distance(u,v) =               ----------------
                              max{distance(x,v) | for each x in the collection }
```